# DriverManager.getConnection not working when program runs from another directory

Tags: java, linux, sqlite

i have a dictionary app that uses sqlite database. when i run the app in the terminal from the 
path that jar file exist with this command `java -jar RememberDict.jar` it works, but when i run it from somewhere other than where the application exists, it gives me errors that i believe it comes from this code:

```
try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +"raw" + File.separator + "dict.db");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("connot connect to words.db");
        throw new Exception("Cannot connect to words.db");
    }
```

so to be specific when i run for example this command
`java -jar ~/NetBeansProjects/RememberDict/dist/RememberDict.jar`

it gives error like this:

```
connot connect to words.db
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at database.Database.getFavWords(Database.java:122)
at rememberdict.FavoritesPanel.<init>(FavoritesPanel.java:36)
at rememberdict.GUIController.<init>(GUIController.java:62)
at rememberdict.RememberDict$1.run(RememberDict.java:11)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

EDIT:

i think i found the solution, my database file (dict.db) is in the raw folder that exist in the same folder that the jar file is located. and actually i wanted to load database file from where the jar file exist. with previous code java can't find database file and those exceptions are thrown, after a while i came up with this solution:

```
String separator = File.separator;
String databasePath = Database.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
String currentDir = databasePath.substring(0, databasePath.lastIndexOf(separator) + 1) + "raw" + separator + "dict.db";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + currentDir);
```

i think previous code despite of not finding the file can load database file if we run the app from the location that jar file exists.

Comment: Let me ask why you're throwing an exception within the catch clause?

Comment: i use it to have a specific exception message that i know where comes from so with `System.out.println("connot connect to words.db");` it's not necessary.

Comment: So did you write this code? Or you've copied it from somewhere else, and you don't understand how it works? The application is obviously hardcoded to look for the driver file in one place; I really don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill yes i write it by myself maybe you expect something like: `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:raw" + File.separator + "dict.db"` but all i have done is that to be sure that database path is absolute and maybe the problem is there. but my question is why this code runs without problem from the jar file location but when i want to run it from somewhere else it didn't work and gives the errors that you can see.

Comment: Because it uses a relative path to the database? Again, I do t understand what you don't understand.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill with previous code i thought that i can get jar file path and relative to it database file path. but i was wrong and `System.getProperty("user.dir")` just gives the current working directory where i am running Java not jar file location.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` will return the directory where the program is running, not the home folder.

So in this case, the sqlite file should always be the same folder as your java program locates.